# Qt Emails input widget

Tags: c++, qt

I want input emails widget like on Google email or other emails service.
http://postimg.org/image/7pnb42gyj/

If I input spase, previous text to label or some other icon.
How can i do this with standard Qt widgets?

I try to do this with `QListWidget`, set iconmode, and last item set `QLineEdit` as last element. And if I set listmode, `QLineEdit` showing, if iconmode - not.
How can I make it?

```
qhbl = new QHBoxLayout();
qlw = new QListWidget();
qlw->setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);
qlw->setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);
connect(qlw, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),
         SLOT(showContextMenuForWidget(const QPoint &)));
qlw->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);


addNewElement("test111111111");
addNewElement("test222222222");
addNewElement("test3333");
addNewElement("test4444");

QListWidgetItem* qlwiItem = new QListWidgetItem();
qle = new QLineEdit();
qle->setText("input");
connect(qle, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(addNewElement()));
qle->setFixedWidth(100);
qle->setMinimumWidth(90);
qle->setMaximumWidth(110);

qlw->addItem(qlwiItem);
qlw->setItemWidget(qlwiItem, qle);
qhbl->addWidget(qlw);
ui->centralWidget->setLayout(qhbl);
```

Comment: I'd go with a [FlowLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html), or simply a QHBoxLayout, where your last item is a `QLineEdit` or similar. Once you accept an email address, you add a custom widget before the QLineEdit.

Comment: Such a widget doesn't exist out of the box. You need some clever logic.

Comment: @peppe what did you mean?

Comment: That there isn't such a widget shipped with Qt. Maybe there's one in KDE, try searching in their Frameworks. Otherwise you need to write one yourself, by a clever combination of a line edit, a flow layout, a custom widget for the "already got" email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html). It looks not so nice like your picture, but works fine and fast.

My easy example solving your problem:

```
void myHiglLight::highlightBlock(const QString &text)
{
    QTextCharFormat myClassFormat;
    myClassFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
    myClassFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
    myClassFormat.setBackground(Qt::green);
    QString pattern = "\\b[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z][a-z]\\b";

    QRegExp expression(pattern);
    int index = text.indexOf(expression);
    while (index >= 0) {
        int length = expression.matchedLength();
        setFormat(index, length, myClassFormat);
        index = text.indexOf(expression, index + length);
    }
}
```

That is work for me when input easy mails. You just need more complex regular expression validator.

Comment: No, this is not good idea, because i want a input string like in email services. It is mean, that, if a email in my adress list, email change to name and surname(for example).

Comment: Its easy to do with handling `textChanged()` signal and using `QRegExp` at connected slot.